# Illustrate back transformed GLS with visreg()

Tags: r, visualization, nlme

I have a GLS with a logarithmic transformed dependent variable. Using visreg() for visualization gives an error code:

```
 library(visreg); library(nlme)
 fit1 <- gls(log(Ozone) ~ Wind , data=na.omit(airquality))
 visreg(fit1,"Wind",trans=exp,ylab="Ozone")
```

Interestingly the very same works just fine with a LM:

```
library(visreg); library(nlme)
fit2 <- lm(log(Ozone) ~ Wind , data=na.omit(airquality))
visreg(fit2,"Wind",trans=exp,ylab="Ozone")
```

Comment: `try(visreg(fit1,"Wind",trans=exp,ylab="Ozone"))` works neither

Comment: The issue is that visreg doesn't have a method for your model's class, "glm"...glm has a predict method but not a model.frame one. Try defining that method for glm objects

Comment: Really? Because `visreg(fit1,"Wind",trans=I,ylab="Ozone")` works fine. Just back transforming does not work.

Comment: fit2 is an object of class lm...it has the predict and model.frame methods neccisary for visreg

Comment: ...sry, meant to say "gls" not "glm"

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The code im my last comment was wrong. I have just edited it. Try `visreg(fit1,"Wind",trans=I,ylab="Ozone")`. It works with a GLS. I can't use a GLM for other reasons.

Comment: The error is about the lack of finite `ylim` values.  A quick work around is to put in your own `ylim` - e.g., `ylim = c(0, 120)`.